# Universes from sets of logical relations

Tags: lo.logic, relation-algebra

Consider any set $I$ and any logical structure $L$. Let $R$ denote some set of $I$-relations over $L$, i.e. each element $r\in R$ sends each $I$-tuple $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ of elements $x_i\in L$ to a value $\text{true}$, or $\text{false}$.

> **Example.** Assume $L = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $I = \mathbb{N}$. Let $R$ denote the set of logical relations of the form
>
> $r_{i, j, k}((x_i)_{i\in I})$ = true if $x_ix_jx_k$ is a line,
>
> $r_{i, j, k, m, n}((x_i)_{i\in I})$ = true if $x_n = x_ix_j\cap x_kx_m$.

**Definition 1.** By a *$R$-configuration* $c$ denote a subset $c\subseteq R$. Let $\text{Conf}(R)$ denotes the set of all $R$-configurations.

**Definition 2.** For any configurations $c , d \in \text{Conf}(R)$ we will say that $c\Rightarrow d$ if $\displaystyle{\bigwedge_{r\in c} r\Rightarrow \bigwedge_{r'\in d} r'},\text{where }\wedge, \Rightarrow\text{ denote logical operators `and', `implies'.}$

**Definition 3.** For any configurations $c, d \in \text{Conf}(R)$ we will say that $d$ is a  *simplification* of $c$ if there are configurations $c_1,\ldots, c_l,d_1, d_2,\ldots , d_l\in \text{Conf}(R)$ with $c_i\subsetneq c$, $c_i\Rightarrow d_i$, $d = \cup_{i = 1}^ld_i$.

**Definition 4.** We will say that a configuration $c\in\text{Conf}(R)$ is *initeresting* if there exists a relation $r\in R$ such that

1. $c\Rightarrow r$
2. for each simplification $d\in\text{Conf}(R)$ of $c$ with $d\Rightarrow r$, we have that $d\Leftrightarrow c$.

Denote by $\text{Univ}(R)$ the set of all interesting configurations in $\text{Conf}(R)$.

**Question 1.** Let $n\geq 1$, $L = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $I_n = \{1,\ldots, n\}$. Let $R(n)$ denote the set of logical relations of the form

$r_{i, j, k}((x_i)_{i\in I_n})$ = true if $x_ix_jx_k$ is a line,

$r_{i, j, k, m, n}((x_i)_{i\in I_n})$ = true if $x_n = x_ix_j\cap x_kx_m$.

For which $n\in\mathbb{N}$ it is possible to compute the set $\text{Univ}(R(n))$?

In general it may be difficult to calculate $\text{Univ}(R)$, and the next its subset can be seen as a simplification.

**Definition 5.** For each $n_1, n_2\geq 1$ define the set $\text{Univ}(R)_{n_1, n_2}\subseteq \text{Univ}(R)$ inductively:

1. Let $\text{Univ}(R)_{n_1, 1} = \{c\in \text{Conf}(R)\:|\: c\text{ contains at most }n_1\text{ relations}\}\cap\text{Univ}(R)$.
2. assume that the set $\text{Univ}(R)_{n_1, t - 1}$ is already defined, let $$\text{Univ}(R)_{n_1, t} = \{c_1\cup \ldots\cup c_m\:|\: m\leq n_1, c_i\in\text{Univ}(R)_{n_1, t - 1}\}\cap\text{Univ}(R).$$

**Question 2.** Consider $I_n, L, R(n)$ as in Question 1. For which $n, n_1, n_2\geq 1$ it is possible to compute the set $\text{Univ}(R(n))_{n_1, n_2}$?

**References.**

[Automated Generation of Triangle Geometry Theorems (arxiv article)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.09511)